# Why does the order of these Haskell Parsec combinators matter?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I want to make a simple parser to parse an addition expression. Here is my code:

```hs
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

data Expr = Number Float |
            Add Expr Expr |

number :: Parser Expr
number = do
    n <- try $ many1 digit
    return $ Number $ read n

add :: Parser Expr
add = do
    e1 <- number
    char '+'
    e2 <- number
    return $ Add e1 e2

expr :: Parser Expr
expr =  try number <|> try add
       

p :: String -> Either ParseError Expr
p = parse (do{e <- expr; eof; return e}) "error"
```

But here is the output

```
ghci> parse add "err" "1+2"
Right (Add (Number 1.0) (Number 2.0))
ghci> p "1"
Right (Number 1.0)
ghci> p "1+2"
Left "error" (line 1, column 2):
unexpected '+'
expecting digit or end of input
```

But if I change the order of the `expr` combinators to

```hs
expr :: Parser Expr
expr =  try add <|> try number
```

Then the output changes to

```
ghci> p "1+2"
Right (Add (Number 1.0) (Number 2.0))
```

Why does this happen? I thought the `try` keyword forces the Parsers I am combining to restart after each `<|>`.

I plan on making this much larger so I want to be sure I understand why this is happening now.

My actual program is larger already but this is still causing a problem independantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that when the string `"1+2"` is parsed with `number`, it *succeeds* (admittedly, with some unparsed characters).  The use of `try` only matters if it had failed.

Perhaps another way to show this is to consider the example `try (string "a") <|> try (string "ab")`.  This will succeed in matching any string starting with the character `a`, but it will never match on strings that start with `"ab"`.

If you had tried instead

```hs
exprAll :: Parser Expr
exprAll =  try (number <* eof) <|> try (add <* eof)
```

then you may get the behavior you're looking for.  In this case, the "try"d parser does not succeed until the end-of-file character is reached, so when the `+` is encountered, the parse attempt of `number <* eof` fails and then parsing starts over using `add <* eof`.